# How do I put a dynamic font-size based on the box-size?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, font-size

I'm making a web quiz game based on botany for a university sponsored project to help students in the high school in general. I need the text to always fill the entire box (buttons, question aswers, etc.) to keep it looking nice. Here's how it looks like right now.

[How the game looks (for now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkHHG.jpg)

The CSS for the question text is:

```
.question-text {
        text-align: justify;
        border: 1px solid black;
        letter-spacing: 0px;

        /* --- POSITION --- */
        position: fixed;
        top: 10%;
        left: 1%;

        /* --- SIZE --- */
        width: 75%;
        height: 20%; 
    }
```

Any advice? I'm also taking sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

[**em**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) unit is the way to go with dynamic font-sizes which is relative to:

Font size of the parent, in the case of typographical properties like font-size, and font size of the element itself, in the case of other properties like width.

```
    .question-text {
        // pervouis properties
        /* Font-Size */

        font-size: <numericAmount>em;
     }
```